# Loop inside of a loop concurrency

Tags: python, loops, concurrency, while-loop

I have a program that calls info from a txt file. Each line in the text file corresponds to an entire file in a different directory. I want to read info from the txt file (line 1) and write it in an output file with info from corresponding file in directory (file 1). I need my code to work for multiple files. How can I get each loop to correspond with each other to produce the correct output?

```
import datetime
import glob

f = open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w')
infofile = open('info.txt', 'rt')
num_lines = sum(1 for line in 'info.txt')
count = 0
while count <= num_lines
    for line in infofile: 
        lat = float(line[88:94]) 
        lon = float(line[119:127])
        year = int(line[190:194])
        month = int(line[195:197])
        day = int(line[198:200])
        hour = int(line[201:203])
        minute = int(line[204:206])
        second = int(line[207:209])
        dur = float(line[302:315])
        numpoints = float(line[655:660])
        fov = line[481:497] # field of view?
        sza = float(line[418:426])
        snr = 0.0000 
        roe = 6396.2 
        res = 0.5000
        lowwav = float(lowwav)
        highwav = float(highwav)
        spacebw = (highwav - lowwav)/ numpoints

        d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
        f.write('{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>8.1f}'.format(sza,roe,lat,lon,snr)) # line 1
        f.write("\n")
        f.write('{:>10d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}'.format(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)) # line 2
        f.write("\n")
        f.write( ('{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)) + "UT Solar Azimuth:" + ('{:>6.3f}'.format(sza)) + " Resolution:" + ('{:>6.4f}'.format(res)) + " Duration:" + ('{:>6.2f}'.format(dur))) # line 3
        f.write("\n")
        f.write('{:>21.13f}{:>26.13f}{:>24.17e}{:>12f}'.format(lowwav,highwav,spacebw,numpoints)) # line 4
        f.write("\n")

        path = '/Users/140803/*' 
        files = glob.glob(path)
        for file(count) in files:
            g = open(file, 'r')
            #do stuff
            g.close()

f.close()
infofile.close()
```

Comment: I've edited this post to add the python tag, this will get the right people looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the conversation, it appears that you do not need to have an inner loop at all. You have multiple nested loops that do not need to exist. I have rewritten portions of your code without them here.

Specifically, if you want to iterate over something and count it at the same time, do ***not*** do something like

```
for count in range(3):
    for item in iterator:
        print("%d %s" % (count, item))
```

The output of those loops will be something like

```
0 item1
0 item2
0 item3
1 item1
1 item2
1 item3
2 item1
2 item2
2 item3
```

What you ***do*** want is the `enumerate` function, which runs a counter along side your iterator:

```
for count, item in enumerate(iterator):
    print("%d %s" % (count, item))
```

This will print

```
0 item1
1 item2
2 item3
```

Also, I replaced all `open() ... close()` constructs with `with ...`:

```
import datetime
import glob

path = '/Users/140803/*' 
files = glob.glob(path)

with open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w') as f:
    with open('info.txt', 'rt') as infofile:
        for count, line in enumerate(infofile): 
            lat = float(line[88:94]) 
            lon = float(line[119:127])
            year = int(line[190:194])
            month = int(line[195:197])
            day = int(line[198:200])
            hour = int(line[201:203])
            minute = int(line[204:206])
            second = int(line[207:209])
            dur = float(line[302:315])
            numpoints = float(line[655:660])
            fov = line[481:497] # field of view?
            sza = float(line[418:426])
            snr = 0.0000 
            roe = 6396.2 
            res = 0.5000
            lowwav = float(lowwav)
            highwav = float(highwav)
            spacebw = (highwav - lowwav)/ numpoints

            d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
            f.write('{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>8.1f}'.format(sza,roe,lat,lon,snr)) # line 1
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('{:>10d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}'.format(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)) # line 2
            f.write("\n")
            f.write( ('{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)) + "UT Solar Azimuth:" + ('{:>6.3f}'.format(sza)) + " Resolution:" + ('{:>6.4f}'.format(res)) + " Duration:" + ('{:>6.2f}'.format(dur))) # line 3
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('{:>21.13f}{:>26.13f}{:>24.17e}{:>12f}'.format(lowwav,highwav,spacebw,numpoints)) # line 4
            f.write("\n")

            with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
                #do stuff (to g presumably)
```

While using a counter on `files` may actually be what you want, I find this highly unlikely. I think that you are actually trying to generate a file name based on the info you just loaded and to open that. The problem with globbing is that it is not even guaranteed to return the results it the same order between two different runs of the same program.

Comment: question: I am updating this code and I would like it to iterate through the count in the same way that it does currently, but rather than print the info one after another, I would like it to write the information to the file, then overwrite it when it gets back to the second count. any tips for doing so?

Comment: Yes, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

After running `files = glob.glob(path)`, `files` contains a list of filename strings. When you run `for file in files:`, the variable `file` will contain a string filename. Thus, you can modify the loop as follows:

```
for file in files:
    with open(file) as g: #<--- file is the filename
        #do stuff
```

There is no need to use a counter since the loop already goes through each file in filename.

Comment: thanks but I don't want it to run all the files at once, I want it to run one, then go back to the loop it is nested in, read another line from the txt file, then do this loop (so I thought a counter would be good to keep both loops on same task but not sure how to do this)

Comment: Ok, in that case, read in the entirety of your 'txt file' and save these files into the `files` list. Then run this loop which will go through each of those. I'm not sure why you are relying on `glob` when you  have the filenames you want to open in a text file.

Comment: Nitpick, but you should do `with open(file) as g: ...` instead of `g = open(file) ... g.close()`.

Comment: @alli. In that case, why are you using an inner loop? If you want to do a single operation for an iteration of the outer loop, just do that operation.

Comment: I am new to Python so I can't see the correct way to do this. If I don't nest the loop, the first loop runs and then the second, and all the information from the files gets added on at the end of the output file, not in-between the information from each line in the txt file.

Comment: @alli Hang on a sec. I'm posting something that addresses your fundamental problem.